# Image Library convert from JPEG to

Tags: python, pdf, image-processing, python-imaging-library, resolution

I'm attempting to convert a JPEG file with, 200 dpi, to a PDF file, however, when I save the file as a PDF I think it's changing the dpi to 72, and thus making the image larger. I had a similar problem when initially trying to scale my JPEG image to a smaller size, and was able to solve that by specifying the dpi when I save the image.

```
im = Image.open("Image.jpg")

dpi=im.info['dpi']

if im.size == (2592, 1728):
    out = im.resize((1188,792), Image.ANTIALIAS)
elif im.size == (1728,2592):
    out = im.resize((792,1188), Image.ANTIALIAS)

out.save(project, dpi=dpi)
```

Now when I try to save this JPEG as a PDF, specifying the dpi doesn't seem to make any difference, and I get an image that is larger than my original that looks like it has a lower dpi. Is there a way to mantain a consistent resolution when converting from JPEG to PDF using PIL? Or is there a better way for me to go about doing this?

This is what I have for converting a directory of files from JPEG to PDF:

```
for infile in listing:

    outfile = destpath + os.path.splitext(infile)[0] + ".pdf"
    current = path + infile

    if infile != outfile:
        im = Image.open(current)
        dpi=im.info['dpi']

        im.save(outfile, "PDF", Quality = 100)
```

Comment: What is the dpi value that PIL reads from the jpeg?  Is it, in fact, 200?

Comment: @jedwards yup, i threw a print statement in there and it said the dpi of the jpeg was (200,200).

Comment: I'm quite surprised that PIL supports PDF at all. I'm sure it's a primitive conversion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the CHANGES file of `PIL 1.1.7` sources one can read:

> - Added resolution save option for PDF files.
>
>   Andreas Kostyrka writes: I've included a patched PdfImagePlugin.py
>     based on 1.1.6 as included in Ubuntu, that supports a "resolution"
>     save option. Not great, but it makes the PDF saving more useful by
>     allowing PDFs that are not exactly 72dpi.

So you should be able to do:

```
im.save(outfile, "PDF", resolution=100.0)
```

(seems to work fine on my Ubuntu box).

Comment: Are you sure it works?  On my system, using `identify -verbose` (ImageMagick) I get: `Resolution: 72x72`

Comment: @jedwards, it works for me on Windows too. Remember that Python is case sensitive, I used a capital `R` the first time and it didn't work. I also used an integer for the parameter, I don't know if that makes a difference or not.

Comment: @MarkRandom, it turns out ImageMagick was lying (sort of).  PDF's don't have a DPI by themselves, so I guess it makes sense that ImageMagick reports 72 by default.  Instead, the individual elements contained within a PDF do.  Using Acrobat's preflight check you can look at the individual elements' DPI -- which confirmed that this does work  (`Image.VERSION = 1.1.7`).  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: This worked! though I has to set resolution = 200.0 for the pdf to be the same dimensions as the jpeg. Set at 100.0 and the dimensions were doubled.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [reportlab](http://www.reportlab.com/ftp/reportlab-2.5.tar.gz) library.

```
import sys

from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, flowables

__jpgname = str()
def drawPageFrame(canvas, doc):
    width, height = letter
    canvas.saveState()
    canvas.drawImage(
    __jpgname, 0, 0, height, width,
    preserveAspectRatio=True, anchor='c')
    canvas.restoreState()

def jpg2pdf(pdfname):
    width, height = letter

    # To make it landscape, pagesize is reversed
    # You can modify the code to add PDF metadata if you want
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate(pdfname, pagesize=(height, width))
    elem = []

    elem.append(flowables.Macro('canvas.saveState()'))
    elem.append(flowables.Macro('canvas.restoreState()'))

    doc.build(elem, onFirstPage=drawPageFrame)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    print("Usage: python jpg2pdf.py <jpgname> <pdfname>")
    exit(1)
    __jpgname = sys.argv[1]
    jpg2pdf(sys.argv[2])
```

Answer (score 2):

It is important that PIL parameters are lowercase.

> im.save(outfile, "PDF", quality = 100)

*Quality = 100*    ----will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code that convert any file with .jpg or .JPG extension and convert into pdf, and then delete the images that have been converted. Sorry the comments are in french.

```
import os #necessaire pouvoir supprimer l'image une fois converti et parcourir les fichers dans le dossier
from fpdf import FPDF #necessaire pour convertir les jpg en pdf


for file in os.listdir(): # pour chaque fichiers dans le dossier dans lequel se trouve ce fichier python
if file.endswith(".jpg") or file.endswith(".JPG"): #permet de selectionner les fichers avec l'extension .jpg ou .JPG
    img=os.path.join(file) #convertie le nom du fichier en variable
    pdf = FPDF()
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.set_font('Arial', 'B', 16)
    pdf.image('%s'%img, 3,3,204 ) # les chiffres permettent de positionner l'image sur le pdf : 3mm de la gauche, 3mm du haut, et 204 mm de la gauche pour la fin de l'image
    img2=img[:-4] #supprime les 4 dernières lettres du nom du ficher, à savoir '.jpg' ou '.JPG'
    pdf.output('%s.pdf'%img2,'F') #convertie en pdf
    os.remove('%s'%img) #supprime les fichier jpg ou JPG
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use:

```
import PIL
import PIL.Image

filename = 'filename'
im = PIL.Image.open(filename)

newfilename = 'path.pdf'
PIL.Image.Image.save(newfilename,outfile, "PDF", resoultion = 100.0)
```

I'm using windows and I used pip to install PIL. For some reason it switched to PIL.Image.Image

Comment: I just checked the newest documentation, it looks like it's cleared up where you need PIL.Image.Image.save(filename, format = ' ').

Answer (score 0):

A complete example here:

```
import os
import PIL.Image

def img2pdf(fname):
    filename = fname
    name = filename.split('.')[0]
    im = PIL.Image.open(filename)
    if not os.path.exists('im2pdf_output'):
        os.makedirs('im2pdf_output')
    newfilename = ''.join(['im2pdf_output/',name,'.pdf'])
    PIL.Image.Image.save(im, newfilename, "PDF", resolution = 100.0)
    print("processed successfully: {}".format(newfilename))

files = [f for f in os.listdir('./') if f.endswith('.jpg')]
for fname in files:
    img2pdf(fname)
```

Answer (score -1):

The correct usage of save is:

```
PIL.Image.Image.save(im, newfilename, "PDF", resolution = 100.0)
```

example:

```
path='v:/dev/python/mooc/'
filename = path + '2016_a_milano_001.JPG'
im = PIL.Image.open(filename)
newfilename = path+ 'r.pdf'
PIL.Image.Image.save(im, newfilename, "PDF", resoultion=100.0)
```

Comment: That usage is not "more correct" than im.save(newfilename, "PDF").